# php variable stored in database not echoing inside html

Tags: php, html, parsing, variables, echo

I'm trying to do apparentely a basic thing: echoing a variable stored in database. My document defines the variable content to show:

```
<?php
$myvar = "this_is_my_content";
?>
```

$myvar (for another 100 reasons) is stored in "my_fied" inside html code in the database and retreived wiht a query.

```
$con = "SELECT LEFT(my_field, 2), my_otherfield FROM my_table";
$res = mysql_query($con);
while (list($my_field, $my_otherfield) = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    if ($my_field != "XX"){
        echo $my_field;
        }
}
```

The result should be:

```
Some html content here and this_is_my_content
```

But all I can get is:

```
Some html content here and $myvar
```

I've being trying 100 combinations bwtween changing single quote, double quote, concatenate string and variables, variable variables. Does someone sees what's wrong? Thanks a lot for any suggestions

Comment: Wait, you're storing executable code in your database?  If that's the case, and you haven't already been told how horrible of an idea this is, let me be the first: *that's a horrible idea!*

Comment: Where do you ever use $myvar, is that actually stored in the db?

Comment: If you're storing `<?php $myvar = "this_is_my_content"; ?>` in the database as a string, that is what `echo` will produce. Check your source, it will have the complete PHP opening/closing tags too. This is terrible way to store information as you would need to parse the database return to use your variable.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm aware this is a horrible idea, it's not an online site and I'll keep trying to avoid it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using eval().

```
echo eval($my_field);
```

Also, note.  Storing PHP code in the database is a horrible idea.

Comment: It worked now, thanks! I had to put start and end php tags in the database field content